# Where is the keyboard mouse feature in GNOME 3?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard, shortcut-keys, gnome, mouse

I'm using Gnome 3 on Ubuntu 11.10.

I've used keyboard mouse (accessing mouse with keyboard) earlier by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Num</kbd> to activate it (see http://www.noah.org/wiki/Linux_Keyboard_Mouse).

However, i cannot use it now. How do I activate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the setting, check System Settings > Universal Access, there one can switch it off

now I try to relax again :-)